# Falstad, Micro-Cap, LTspice

Tags: ltspice, falstad

I've just started with Electronics and am enjoying the Falstad simulator for seeing how components work, current flows, etc; really great.
I've become aware of Micro-Cap and was aware of LTspice as, potentially, more useful simulators.
Is there any way of exporting a Falstad circuit into LTspice or vice versa?
Many thanks.

Comment: No, there is not.